# Black Ball: Can a player win a game by first hitting an opponents ball on a free shot?

Tags: rules, pool

In a game where where player 1 is on black and player 2 still has balls remaining on the table. Given the scenarios where player 2 commits a foul giving player 1 a free shot, then on that free shot player 1 first hits one of player 2's remaining balls before sinking the black on the same shot. Does player 1 win in this case? If not, what is the correct flow of play following this?

The WPA rule book states that the "Wrong Ball First" rule is suspended on free shots. However, does this still apply on the black given that you are essentially winning off a foul shot?

Using this version of the rule book for reference: http://wpapool.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/WPA_New_Rules.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The shooter wins the rack if they sink the black ball, and do not commit a foul under the rules.

As it is a free shot, the shooter cannot be called foul under 6.2 Wrong Ball First.

They may of course shoot the cue ball into the opponent ball, so that it contacts the black ball and sinks it.

As this meets the conditions of the introduction to part 5 for winning the rack, they have won, subject to not making an illegal shot and breaching rule 5.14, part (a) for a Loss of Rack foul.

Answer (score -1):

You lose as shot was not called in that manner, i.e. white off opponent's ball first, if called that way is all good. Must call black pocket and if not obvious and easy, how as well, especially if hitting opponent's ball first.

Imagine my black over hole being covered with opponent's ball and I have ball in hand. I must call opponent's ball to pot black for win as unable to hit black directly with white.

Comment: the OP posted the rules. Can you point which rules apply in this situation?

Comment: The rules **do not** require calling the method of the shot or any details **at all**. This answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

**Player 1 loses in this game**. Why?:

- **8-ball made on an illegal shot**: As player 1 has called 8-ball and the pocket, he cannot make contact with any other ball first.

Comment: This is not correct. No shot needs to be called, and it is legal to hit the opponent's object ball first if taking a free shot.

Comment: any reference to support it?

Comment: They're literally the rules of the game. Blackball is not a called shot game, so even saying "called 8-ball" makes the answer wrong. The full rules of blackball are provided in the question itself, see section **5 Blackball**.